handling special characters while loading data from s3 into mysql
In my S3, I have a csv file that looks like this:
"id","created_at","subject","description","priority","status","recipient",   

Now, one the description column's row looks like this:
"for more, please let us know and we add them. but they did not explain why the following request is not working. We get an Unauthorized error. Can we please receive what is needed for this request including the test data?

{
  "errors": [
    "Unauthorized"
  ],
  "result": null,
  "status": 401
}

curl -X POST "https://xx/v1/prefill/eWR1iNBnG8Wj" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 2e05581e8b" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"data\":{\"externalId\":\"string\",\"subId\":\"string\",\"common\":{\"amount\":20000,\"term\":84,\"purpose\":\"REFINANCING\",\"payoutAccount\":{\"iban\":\"string\"},\"payoutAccountHolder\":\"PRIMARY\",..............."

This has normal text but also some special characters. Notice this part in the cell's value :
\"string\",\"subId\":

Now I use such a command to load it into MYSQL:
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://{s3_bucket_name}/{s3_key}'
                    REPLACE
                    INTO TABLE {schema_name}.stg_tickets
                    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
                    FIELDS 
                        TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '"'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    (id, url, @created_at, @updated_at, @external_id, @type, subject, 
                    description, priority, status, recipient, requester_id, 
                    submitter_id, assignee_id, @organization_id, @group_id, 
                    collaborator_ids, follower_ids, @forum_topic_id, @problem_id, 
                    @has_incidents)

This works for all other cases because there are not a lot of commas/special characters in other description rows. But this particular record messes up the columns because it cannot distinguish the description properly. For example, it adds this to the priority column
"""subId"":""string""

Which is not true because this is still a part of the description column.
I want to handle it using the MySQL command itself. Pre-processing the S3 files wouldn't be an option at the moment.
Note: I am running the query using Python.
There are other commas in the description column as well but those don't make an issue.

That doesn't look like a csv, it looks like a tsv file. There's clearly no commas even though in your import statement you tell MySQL to look for commas.

This is a csv file. I have just shown one CELL's value, that's why you don't see any commas. It works for other rows/columns. Just having issues in this particular cell. @Evert

Then you need to actually share sample that that represents the issue. I was referring to what you shared here btw: id    created_at        description   priority     status    . Those are clearly multiple columns and no commas.

I have already shared the particular record from the description column that causes the issue. There are commas within that text column. @Evert

If this sample: \"string\",\"subId\":  is exact value as stored on S3 and meant to be 1 column, not 2 then you basically have a broken CSV file. I don't see an obvious way of fixing this without some kind of pre-processing script.

This isn't about special characters. That's a broken file. The description column contains improperly escaped strings. Instead of "errors": it should contain ""errors"":. RFC4180 specifies that  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote. You need to fix whatever produced the description values. This can't be imported as CSV into any application

If you control whatever produces this file try using uncommon characters for quoting eg § or ¤.

If you did not already do this, maybe it could solve the issue ? (just a wild guess)
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 COLLATE UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI;

ALTER TABLE {schema_name}.stg_tickets CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 COLLATE UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI;


Can you explain a bit?

As you said "This has normal text but also some special characters", I thought that a good thing would be to make sure that the UTF-8 encoding is used everywhere.
So using these commands before your code would be a good precaution.
